# How to serialize inputs and select option to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, serialization

I need to serialize inputs and selected option with JSON datatype in the table below:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="formpiw" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
<table id="tblpiw">
    <tr id="trwil">
        <td width="100">Area</td>
        <td>
            <select id="tdarea"> 
                <option value="a" selected="selected">Area A</option>
                <option value="b">Area B</option>
                <option value="c">Area C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <input required type="text" id="name" />
        </td>
    </tr>

$.ajax({
    url: "piw_proses.php",
    type:"post", 
    data:$( ":input" ).serialize(), 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success:function(response){
```

I can`t get selected value from option!
Inputs were serialized.

Comment: Why not form serialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `name` in select and input:

```
        <select id="tdarea" name="tdarea"> 
            <option value="a" selected="selected">Area A</option>
            <option value="b">Area B</option> 
            <option value="c">Area C</option>
        </select>

        <input required type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a name attribute, to serialize it must have a name attribute check this [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), Additionally you can even use:

```
var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
```